Geom_hline does not appear at intercept I set
I tried to draw horizontal line on geom_point ggplot, but was unsuccessfull. My code:
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = J68_fit, aes(x = v, y = delta, colour = J)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)

The result:

As you can see, there is no horizontal line. Why?

That's because the variable mapped on y isn't a numeric but a character or factor. Try with y = as.numeric(delta).

This works for me:
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(data= data.frame(v=c(1,2,3),delta=c(2,3,6),J=c("1","2","2")), aes(x = v, y = delta, colour = J)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic() + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)


If you try this code do you get the horizontal line or is it not working?
Your theme_classic() looks different to mine (note gridlines). Has this been overwritten? What version of ggplot2 do you have? Mine is 3.4.0.
